# How to create class instance using class as variable?

Tags: angular, typescript

In `typescript` I pass whole class as reference `MyClass` to a function.
How to create new instance of that class in that function?

```
export class MyClass {
}

createClass(MyClass);

function createClass(classReference) {
   const classInstance = new classReference();//not working
}
```

I need it because in angular's `ModuleWithProviders` I cannot call `new MyClass()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
function createClass<T>(classReference: { new (): T }): T {
   return new classReference();
}

let a = createClass(MyClass); // type of a is MyClass
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20MyClass%20%7B%0A%7D%0A%0AcreateClass(MyClass)%3B%0A%0Afunction%20createClass%3CT%3E(classReference%3A%20%7B%20new%20()%3A%20T%20%7D)%3A%20T%20%7B%0A%20%20%20return%20new%20classReference()%3B%0A%7D))

Answer (score 0):

In your ModuleWithProviders you could instead use:

```js
{ provide: ProviderToReplace, useClass: MyClass }
```

[See more here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#the-provider-class-and-provide-object-literal)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know that but that class is not a provider - it's array of classes with mostly data.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll leave this here in case it solves someone else's problem 